# Прямоугольник С++

Tags: c++, c++11, олимпиада

> *На входе программы есть четыре натуральных числа a, b, c и d, записанные в одной строке через пропуск. В ответ следует вывести сумму заданных чисел, если существует прямоугольник с длинами сторон a, b, c, d и сообщение No в противном случае.*

***Входящие данные #1:***

***7 4 4 7***

***Выходные данные #1:***

***22***

> *Помогите пожалуйста с задачей, проходящей на 90% тестов*

код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    if(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0)
    {
        if(a * b == c * d || a == d && b == c)
        {
            cout << a + b + c + d << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: сравнение умножений `a * b == c * d` нужно полностью убрать. Неправильных прямоугольников у вас будет очень много. Например `1 * 12 == 2 * 6 == 3 * 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, числа натуральные — значит, проверка на "больше нуля" не нужна. Остается проверка попарного равенства сторон. Для a это b, c или d — ну и, соответственно, вторая пара...

```
if ((a == b && c == d) || (a == c && b == d) || (a == d && c == b))
    cout << a+b+c+d;
else
    cout << "No";
```